# Как с помощью одного из операторов функции прервать ее выполнение без использование директивы return

Tags: javascript

```
ctx.reply(operator1,operator2)
```

Условно говоря, если `Operator1` равен `false`, необходимо, чтобы функция `reply` вообще ничего не делала.

Answer (score 3):

```
function reply(operator1, operator2) {
  if (operator1 !== false) {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

> reply все равно вернет undefined, мне нужно чтобы просто не выполнился
>   код

```
function reply(operator1, operator2) {
  if (operator1 === false) {
    throw new Error("operator1 is false");
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: reply все равно вернет undefined, мне нужно чтобы просто не выполнился код

Answer (score 0):

```
function reply(operator1, operator2) { 
    if (operator1 === false) { 
         break;
    } 
}
```